# Erro com caracteres Especiais GET HTTP

Tags: java, http

Estou com alguns problemas na hora de fazer GETs HTTP.

Quando o texto da página tem algum caractere especial, a resposta acaba se deformando.

Exemplo:

`os participantes dever&amp;atilde;o:`

quando o texto original era `os participantes deverão`.

O código que estou usando para fazer esse get é o seguinte:

```
        try {
        URL url = new URL("***Url***");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String strTemp = "";
        while (null != (strTemp = br.readLine())) {
            System.out.println(strTemp);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Alguma ideia do que pode estar causando esse problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essas construções do tipo `&amp;` e `&atilde;` são chamadas *HTML character entities*. Elas não são erros e provavelmente já vieram da página original assim. São usadas para representar caracteres reservados do HTML.

Veja [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode) algumas maneiras de substitui-las pelos caracteres apropriados. A mais popular parece ser usar o método [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) da biblioteca *Apache Commons*.

Comment: Funcionou para mim. Obrigado.